# Declaring a variable with no initialiser in Flutter, with null safety

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to implement Firebase authentication into my app with Flutter and my coding worked fine initially, although since I have migrated the project to null safety the authentication no longer works. I think I have 'isolated' where that is.

For example, if we take my password reset TextField, this is what the TextField looks like in terms of the code:

```
  TextField _buildEmailTextField() {
    return TextField(
      controller: _emailController,
      focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email',
        hintText: 'email@address.com',
        errorText: model.emailErrorText,
        enabled: model.isLoading == false,
      ),
      autocorrect: false,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      onChanged: model.updateEmail,
      onEditingComplete: _submit,
    );
  }
```

Of course, to handle changes to the TextField, you can see that I have added an updateEmail function `onChanged: model.updateEmail`. The function itself looks like this:

```
void updateEmail(String email) => updateWith(email: email);
```

And the updateWith function looks like this:

```
  void updateWith({
    String email = '',
    bool isLoading = false,
    bool submitted = false,
  }) {
    this.email = email;
    this.isLoading = isLoading;
    this.submitted = submitted;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Prior to null safety, I didn't need to initialise the variables in `updateWith` with a value, so it would have looked like this:

```
  void updateWith({
    String email,
    bool isLoading,
    bool submitted,
  }) {
    this.email = email;
    this.isLoading = isLoading;
    this.submitted = submitted;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The error from Firebase is:

```
[firebase_auth/missing-email] An email address must be provided
```

And I think this is caused by the fact that I am now having to initialise the `email` variable in `updateWith`, and I am using an empty string. Therefore, even though I am typing in an email into the TextField, when I submit, it submits the empty string, so that Firebase tells me I haven't submitted an email. I have tried it instead using email as a nullable value, like so:

```
  void updateWith({
    String? email,
    bool isLoading = false,
    bool submitted = false,
  }) {
    this.email = email!;
    this.isLoading = isLoading;
    this.submitted = submitted;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

But then that gives me the error:

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

How do I make my updateWith function work now that I have migrated to null safety? As I say, it worked fine prior to null safety, so I am confident with the logic. It's just that having to initialise `email` with a variable within the function now means that initial variable is submitted to firebase, rather than the typed-in email address. Is there a way to make this work, or a way I can rewrite my `updateEmail` and `updateWith` functions, so that they don't have to be initialised with a value?

If you need me to provide any additional information, I would be happy to. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: `String? email,` enabling null value can you try to replace with `required String email`

Comment: Your initial method is already not really following the Fultter way of writing those methods. Is it on purpose that setting the email to something will set the other two variables to null? Because that's what you did and now you transferred it to instead set them to false, which seems equally wrong. Can you describe what `updateWith(email: email)` should do to all three fields in plain English?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh That does seem to work.

Comment: @nvoigt You're definitely correct, in that it doesn't seem to be the right way of doing things, although it does work with the above suggestion and the one in the answer. The knowledge/code came initially from a Udemy course on the subject and actually, the purpose is simply to handle a change in the textfield, as far as I know. If you have a more proper suggestion, I would absolutely be grateful for it, as I am always keen to learn how to do things better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is very unintuitive for Dart/Flutter developers, unless you do it using the common pattern. The point of those optional parameters in methods like this normally is to pass only a few of them, leaving the rest untouched. So for example, you could call `updateWith(email: 'test@example.com')` and *only* the `email` will be updated but `isLoading` and `submitted` will remain unchanged. You can only achieve this if the parameters are nullable, so you have a marker/value for "wasn't set at all" that you can check for.

For example:

```
void updateWith({
    String? email,
    bool? isLoading,
    bool? submitted,
  }) {
    this.email = email ?? this.email;
    this.isLoading = isLoading ?? this.isLoading;
    this.submitted = submitted ?? this.submitted;

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

If `email` is a required parameter and the other two will be set to defaults anyway, you don't need named parameters at all. Just make it a normal method with normal positional parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It's exactly right, that email is the only one that will be updated and the others will remain unchanged. It does seem to be working now, so thank you. I'll try and be more careful with my code going forward, so that I am actually understanding what it is that I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Change `void updateEmail(String email) => updateWith(email: email);`

to `void updateEmail(String? email) => updateWith(email: email);`

Comment: That does seem to work, thanks! The error now is `[firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.` which is correct, as I know no users exist (I'm just testing).

Answer (score 1):

Null-safety doesn't mean never using `null`.  If something worked before null-safety, it can still work afterward by using nullable types.

Functions such as `updateWith` and `copyWith` usually are meant to use *only* the supplied arguments and to leave the rest alone.  That consequently usually means making the parameters nullable:

```dart
 void updateWith({
    String? email,
    bool? isLoading,
    bool? submitted,
  }) {
    this.email = email ?? this.email;
    this.isLoading = isLoading ?? this.isLoading;
    this.submitted = submitted ?? this.submitted;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

(Note that your original implementation of `updateWith` didn't do that and unconditionally clobbered fields with `null` if the caller didn't provide them.  If that's actually the behavior you want, then the function name is a misnomer.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was intending the function to do, so thank you for pointing that out to me. I'm still learning, but I understand what you mean and it is working with those changes you have suggested, so thank you.